# Dynamically creating routes with Express and EJS template from JSON response

Tags: json, node.js, express, ejs

I have a number of products and would like to dynamically create a route for each one so when I add a product to the CMS that I am doing an API call to get JSON, it automatically creates the page instead of hand coding it.

[JSON Tree](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbbf8dc8)

Express:

```
var scopedEntries;

//get contentful entries
client.getEntries() //get entries
.then(function (entries){
  scopedEntries = entries; //assigning globally to later pass into routes
  console.log(entries.items[0].fields.companyName); //log data
}); // end of promise

router.get('/test:id', function (req, res) {
  //console.log(scopedEntries);
  res.render('test' + req.params.id, {
    entries: scopedEntries
    });
  });
```

Template Example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TEST APP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= entries.items[0].fields.companyName %></h1>
    <h2><%= entries.items[1].fields.productName %></h2>
    <p>Description: <%= entries.items[1].fields.productDescription %></p>
    <p>Size: <%= entries.items[1].fields.sizetypecolor %></p>
    <p>Price: <%= entries.items[1].fields.price %></p>
    <p>SKU: <%= entries.items[1].fields.productDescription %></p>
    <img src="<%= entries.includes.Asset[0].fields.file.url %>" alt="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

So Ideally, there is a page for each item in the JSON response and It's dynamically created using EJS in the express route. How would I do this properly.

Also, JSON is not final JSON. The schema hasn't been fully seeded yet so I will need to adapt it to my tree.

Comment: You probably don't want to create a route for every product.  Probably, you want to create a single route that handles all your products and then specify a parameter in your route (either part of the route or a query parameter) that tells the single route handler which product it should show.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Specifically how would I do that?

Comment: To do what I suggested above, we'd have to understand your overall URL design for the site so we could suggest exactly how to fit a product parameter into the URL structure.

Comment: And could I have IDS as product names

Comment: Imagine if the test route was /product/:ID

Comment: It really depends upon your overall URL design.  But, you could have `/product/view/:productName`.  or `/product/view/:productID` and have one route handler that handles all your products. If someone enters a productName or productID that does not exist, then you'd just do a nice 404 page.

Comment: How would I populate the right data into the template?

Comment: Specifically that's where I'm struggling.

Comment: Can all products be displayed from the same template?  Or are you trying to have a unique template for every single product?  Your question is lacking a lot of detail for us to know how to help in any specific way.

Comment: I'm trying to do this with one template

Comment: Much easier with one template.  Do you understand how data gets into templates?  You pass a bunch of data to `res.render()` and the template engine uses that data to build the page form the template, incorporating your data where the template says to put the data.  So, you'd take the incoming product specified in the URL, look up a bunch of data on it and then pass all that data to `res.render()` along with the template name.  That's how Express templates work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to create a new route for every product. Probably, you want to create a single route that handles all your products and then specify a parameter in your route (either part of the route or a query parameter) that tells the single route handler which product it should show.

How exactly to do it depends upon the overall URL design for your site.  But, you could have a route for `/product/view/:productName`. or `/product/view/:productID` and have one route handler that handles all your products. If someone enters a `productName` or `productID` that does not exist, then you'd just do a nice 404 page.

Your one route handler for this route would get the productName or productID (depending upon which one you want to design for) out of the URL and then look up all the relevant information about that product in your database.  It would then put all that data into a data structure (probably an object with lots of properties) and then pass that data structure to `res.render(templateName, data)`.  The template engine will then put the data into the generated HTML page as your template specifies.

If some products display different types of information, then your template has to be a superset of everything that needs to be displayed and you code the template to show various information based on whether it is present or not in the data passed to `res.render()`.

Comment: Also, the question's current code has almost all the pieces in place already; it just needs to move the ID from out of the template name, and instead of passing the entire product list, use the ID to find the correct entry in the product list and pass only that one to the template.

Comment: Great !! But i have a question how we sent productID from the client side can you help Please !!

Comment: @SaadSohail - I would suggest you write your own question and fully describe your situation and show the code you have so far.